How to construct the HHL oracle circuit when the entries of $A$ are described by a polynomial?
Among other assumptions, HHL's algorithm assumes that the entries of the coefficient matrix $A$ (where $Ax=b$ is the linear system to be solved) can be realized by means of an oracle circuit $U_A$.  Say that the entries of $A$ are described by a polynomial $p$ of some degree $d$, e.g., $A_{i,j} = p(i,j)$ if $|i - j| \leq s$ and $A_{i,j} = 0$ otherwise. Is there any chance to construct an oracle circuit in such a case as demanded by HHL? As possible approaches, qubitization seems not to fit because it operates on matrices, while an application of nonlinear transformation of complex amplitudes (e.g., this paper) comes with a positive error probability (among other issues).
Any pointer would be appreciated.

CW because it's too long for a comment

For simplicity let's assume that $p(i,j)$ has integer coefficients and is symmetric (thus, $p(i,j)=p(j,i)\in \mathbb Z$, so $A$ is hermitian ab initio).
I think with appropriate bounds on the degree $d$ of $p$ and of the (bit) complexity of the coefficients, you could find a way to oracularly decompose $A$ into a sum of a polynomial number of other matrices, for example by coming up with a slightly more complex polynomial $p'$ for each of the other non-zero entries of the rows and columns, and Trotterizing accordingly.
In particular, could you decompose $A$ as $A=A_1+A_2+A_3+\cdots + A_s$, where $A_i$ only has at most a single non-zero entry for any given row?  From that sum I guess you could use the Lie-Trotter product formula to simulate $e^{-itA}$, which is what HHL requires in its phase estimation.
